# PyQt6: AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'FramelessWindowHint'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt6

I've tried everything I can think of, but no matter what I do, I get this error whenever I try to set the window's attribute "FramelessWindowHint." First, here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

class MainApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainApp()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This is my code. When I run it without the line `self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`, it works fine, and I can add other elements, I just stripped it down for the question. The "ID" for FramelessWindowHint, at least in PyQt5, is 2048. If I try this using PyQt5, it works fine, but when I try replacing the `from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt` with PyQt5, it throws an error:

```
TypeError: setWindowFlags(self, Qt.WindowFlags): argument 1 has unexpected type 'WindowType'
```

I have searched everywhere I can think of, and nobody else has this problem as far as I can find. I looked in https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/api/qtcore/qt.html but it doesn't say anything about this, it shows `FramelessWindowHint` normally.

If anyone else has had this problem or knows the solution, please let me know. I'll try to reply as soon as possible, TIA!

Comment: PyQt6 has changed the way flags and enums are dealt with, now they are only accessible through the flag names. Try with `Qt.WindowFlags.FramelessWindowHint`.

Comment: @musicamante Wow, that was a lot simpler than I thought it would be, thanks so much! Would you mind posting that as an answer so I can mark it as one?

Comment: I don't think there would be need for that, as the question already has a very similar duplicate [How to check MouseButtonPress event in PyQt6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66235661/how-to-check-mousebuttonpress-event-in-pyqt6)

Comment: Note: It's actually `Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint`