# Why is there no QtWebEngine in the Qt6?

Tags: qt, qtwebengine, qt6

Why there is no QtWebEngine in the Qt6? Is it depricated? Should I use a new widget?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt6 is a big change so for compatibility reasons Qt does not provide this module, it will be provided in Qt 6.2 as this post: [Add-on support in Qt 6.0 and beyond](https://www.qt.io/blog/add-on-support-in-qt-6.0-and-beyond) points out.

> For Qt 6.2 we are planning to provide the following additional
> libraries:
>
> - Qt Bluetooth
> - Qt Data Visualization
> - Qt Lottie Animation
> - Qt Multimedia
> - Qt NFC
> - Qt Positioning
> - Qt Quick Dialogs: Folder, Message Box
> - Qt Remote Objects
> - Qt Sensors
> - Qt SerialBus
> - Qt SerialPort
> - Qt WebChannel
> - **Qt WebEngine**
> - Qt WebSockets
> - Qt WebView

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

So you will have to wait for that release that according to what was announced will be available for September 2021

Comment: QtWebEngine is now available.

Comment: How can I import it on qt 6?

Comment: @user See the docs: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebengine-index.html

Comment: That page does not say how to import anything. Luckly I am using Python and I figured it out by inspecting the code with `pdb` and `dir(PyQt6)`.  By guessing I figure out the path `PyQt6.QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineSettings.PlaybackRequiresUserGesture`, and once I run the code, qt tells me `'QWebEngineSettings.PlaybackRequiresUserGesture' will stop working. Please use 'QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.PlaybackRequiresUserGesture' instead`. QT documentation is the worse, most of their examples do not show how to import anything (if they have an example code).

Comment: @user I do not understand you, the problem that is discussed in the post is about the Qt WebEngine module in Qt6, instead it seems that you have a different problem: 1. the problem is with PyQt6 and 2. It is with pdb. So in that case I recommend you create a new post explaining your problem in detail, the comments section does not serve to solve other problems.

Comment: @user From what I see the problem is not from QtWebEngine but from a change introduced in PyQt6 (in some of my posts explain it). In your case, change `QWebEngineSettings.PlaybackRequiresUserGesture` to `QWebEngineSettings.WebAttribute.PlaybackRequiresUserGesture`. See for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66235661/how-to-check-mousebuttonpress-event-in-pyqt6/66235879#66235879

Comment: @user Also read https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2020-April/042836.html