# What is analog of setWindowFlags in PyQt6?

Tags: python, pyqt6

While trying to migrate pyqt5 code to pyqt6, i have occured a problem with setWindowFlags:
`self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)` returns an error:
**AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'WindowStaysOnTopHint'**. So wat is the similar in PyQt6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check MouseButtonPress event in PyQt6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66235661/how-to-check-mousebuttonpress-event-in-pyqt6)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`QtCore.Qt.WindowType.WindowStaysOnTopHint`